# Github page: readme before file list, not after?

Tags: github, readme

Is there a way to make a repository's page on Github show its README.md *above* its list of top-level files?  Scrolling past that list is tedious when it's long (for one's own repos), and when browsing others' repos (when the readme means more than the filenames).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this custom user stylesheet:

```
DIV.repository-content {
    display: table
}
DIV.js-repo-meta-container {
    display: table-caption
}
DIV.readme {
    display: table-header-group
}
```

This turns the DIV that groups most of the page's elements into a table, and then makes the README element a table header. This moves it top of the "table."  I also turned the "meta" element into a caption for the table so it appears above the README, because that's informative when browsing repositories.

Obviously this styleseet is fragile and will break when GitHub decides to redo how they style their pages.

For this custom stylesheet to work it needs to be set as a custom CSS in your browser.  This may be easy ([Internet Explorer](https://www.itsupportguides.com/knowledge-base/computer-accessibility/how-to-use-a-custom-style-sheet-css-with-internet-explorer/)), difficult ([Firefox](https://superuser.com/questions/318912/how-to-override-the-css-of-a-site-in-firefox-with-usercontent-css)), needing an extension ([Chrome](https://www.itsupportguides.com/knowledge-base/computer-accessibility/how-to-use-a-custom-style-sheet-css-with-google-chrome/)), or impossible (Edge?).

Comment: Yes, for Firefox: alt, help, troubleshooting, profile dir, open dir, rightclick, new folder, chrome.  In that folder create a file userContent.css.  In that file put the code `@-moz-document domain(github.com) { ...DIV DIV DIV }`.

Comment: I didn't know about "user stylesheets."  So this changes how all github pages look in *my* Firefox.  I can't directly change how my github pages look to anyone else.  Good enough for now.

Answer (score 1):

Nope, I think github is just setup to always show files first. sorry :'(